# Extracting vectors from a dataframe within a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I have a dataset that contains GPS data for multiple objects, as well as a time component. The dataframe is split into 2 columns: Object and Time. However, the each row in the time column corresponds to a dataframe within the Object column, which contains a unique name/ID of each object (there are 5) and the X, Y, and Z coordinates at that instance of time.

My question is, is there a way to extract just one of the ID's and coordinates from the "dataframe within a dataframe" to create a new DF with the XYZ coordinates, ID, and time? The ultimate goal would be to have new 5 dataframes for each object so I can individually plot the location for each object.

Sorry if the question is confusing and there is no reproducible code, I have no idea how to create a column within a dataframe that contains more dataframes.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Without test data it's difficult to answer but something along the lines of

```
coord <- df1$Time
coord <- do.call(rbind, coord)
merge(df1['ID'], coord)
```

might be a solution.

Tested with the following data:

```
set.seed(2020)
df1 <- data.frame(ID = 1:5)
df1$Time <- lapply(df1$ID, function(i){
  data.frame(ID = i, Time = Sys.time(),
             X = runif(1, 0, 180),
             Y = runif(1, 0, 180),
             Z = runif(1, 0, 180))
})
```